# How to create a multiple selection list?

Tags: python-3.x

Basically for part of my university project I want to ask students their availability for a study buddy app. I want them to be able to have multiple options which they can select as well.

Below is the current code I have -

```
chosen =""
chosen_list=[]
available_list = ['Monday Morning', 'Monday Afternoon', 'Monday Evening', 'Tuesday Morning', 'Tuesday Afternoon', 'Tuesday Evening']
print ('What is your availability?')
while chosen !="0":
    print ('Available times:' + available_list)
    chosen = input('Choose a time or 0 to quit')
    if chosen in available_list:
        chosen_list.append(chosen)
        print (chosen_list)
```

But I'm coming up with this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "G:/University/Intro to Programming/Assessment Project/Step
>   1/.idea/step1new.py", line 132, in  What is enter code
>   hereyour availability?
>       print ('Available times:' + available_list) TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Can someone please advise me on this?

Comment: Change the `+` to `,`

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is in the error. Change the `+` to `,`

```
print ('Available times:' , available_list)
```

When using the `+` sign with the list, python is looking for a list to add its values to, however it is met with a `str`

Comment: no you cant, the error clearly says that you cant convert list implicitly to string.

Comment: @ShiftN'Tab : note taken. However the OP doesn't explicitly state how they want the output to be viewed. Both output. Yours is better thought :)

Comment: Beginner will not always explicitly state what they want but it is good to tell them what's going on or later your answer will confuse them.

Comment: @ShiftN'Tab Respect (Y)

Answer (score 0):

> The  error says TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str
>   implicitly

You can try this

```
print ('Available times: ' + " ,".join(available_list))
```

`" ,".join(list)` will convert a list in a string object as a result:

```
'Available times: Monday Morning, Monday Afternoon, Monday Evening, Tuesday Morning, Tuesday Afternoon, Tuesday Evening'
```